# Is a hole at a vertical asymptote recognized?

Tags: rational-functions

If I have a hole in a rational function, but the hole is located at a vertical asymptote, is the hole still recognized? For example in the equation (x+3)(x+1)/(x+1)(x+1) I will have a hole at -1, but a vertical asymptote also at -1.

Comment: Don't bother drawing the "hole", just draw the asymptote.  The fact that there is a vertical asymptote there directly implies that the function is undefined at that point which is all that a "hole" would represent.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "hole" is really just a point where the function is undefined, but it just so happens that the function "looks smooth" around the point. This is called a *removable discontinuity*, and is defined as a point $c$ so that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ exists and is finite, but $f(c)$ is undefined. By contrast, an asymptote occurs when the left and right hand limits are individually $\pm\infty$ and in particular not finite. Now let's take your example: $f(x)=(x+1)/(x+1)^2$, and take the limit as $x$ goes to $-1$. There's no hole here, since the limits go to $\pm\infty$ and is not finite. So we don't draw a "hole", but just the asymptote instead!